# Handling multiple post requests with locking

Tags: node.js, locking

So I have to write some NodeJS code that does the following: whenever a post request is made, I attempt to execute some program; if the program is already executing (because of a previous request), I ignore the request. If not, I execute the program. I'm using NodeJS child_process.exec to accomplish this; however, there's no way for me to know when exec(program) terminates; I thought of using execSync, but this simply blocks any requests until the program is done executing, instead of ignoring them completely. Here is the code I have right now:

```
function fun () {
  execFile('C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe', ['package.json'],);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execFile` is an `EventEmitter`, so you can listen for events that occur while `execFile` operates, including the `exit` event, which tells you the process has completed.

```
  ignoreNextRequest = true;
  execFile('C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe', ['package.json']).once('exit', (code, signal) => {
    // Your code to handle the end of the process here.
    ignoreNextRequest = false;
});
```